# saving large streaming data in python

Tags: python, sql

I have a large amount of data coming in  every second in the form of python dictionaries, right now I am saving it to mySQL server as they come in but that creates a backlog thats more than a few hours. What is the best way to save the data locally and move it to a mySQL server every hour or so as a chunk to save time.I have tried redis but it cant save a list of these dictionaries which I can later move to mySQL.

Comment: You can store a serialised dictionary string in a Redis list if the dictionaries be can be serialised using Python pickle or JSON.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A little-known fact about the Python native `pickle` format is that you can happily concatenate them into a file.

That is, simply open a file in `append` mode and `pickle.dump()` your dictionary into that file. If you want to be extra fancy, you could do something like timestamped files:

```
def ingest_data(data_dict):
    filename = '%s.pickles' % date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d_%H')
    with open(filename, 'ab') as outf:
        pickle.dump(data_dict, outf, pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)


def read_data(filename):
    with open(filename, 'rb') as inf:
        while True:
            yield pickle.load(inf)  # TODO: handle EOF error
```