# Python script for streaming TCP/IP data and saving it as .txt file

Tags: python, tcp, streaming, data-stream

I have a software which has the option of streaming data as TCP/IP data. The used port is specified. Although I am not sure **what should be the "hostname"?** I want to receive this data using a python script on the same computer as the software and save it as a .txt file. **How can I save it as a .txt file?**

I am completely new to this and also Python programming. Would be nice if someone could give an idea **how to go about it and in terms of time frame** as well. **Is it something that I can manage by watching tutorials or would it require in depth understanding of many concepts (if yes, what all?).**

Thanks in advance!

Comment: if it is the same computer then `localhost` or `127.0.0.1`

Comment: @furas or `::1` if you're using IPv6

Comment: @SamMason yes. Should works also `0.0.0.0` or even any IP of local network card

Answer (score 1):

The host is the IP Address to which your device needs to be connected to. If you are going to connect remotely your device, you could simply use
**localhost**.

For saving data I would like to suggest following this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46951015/saving-large-streaming-data-in-python).